# Usage of "let loose"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I've got some examples with the phrase "let loose":

> In this competition, dogs are let loose to chase a jack rabbit over desert
> terrain.
>
> Ellen was laughing like a child let loose in a sweet shop

These two examples are from Oxford Dictionary.

> I was uptight, wanna let loose
>
> I was dreaming of bigger things in
>
> Wanna leave my own life behind.

This one is from Imagine Dragons' song "Thunder".

So, the question is next: why can we not to use "be" in the last two examples? I thought, "let loose" is like an adjective.

Comment: 'Let loose' has an intransitive sense (meaning break free / break out) as well as a transitive use (he let me loose) which can be passivised (I was let loose by him).

Answer (score 1):

The third example uses a rather unusual sense of 'let loose':

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20loose) has an example of the intransitive use of 'let loose' (a multi-word verb):

> *let loose* [verb] (2): to produce (something, such as a cry) in a sudden and forceful way
>
> *The crowd let loose an enormous groan when the pass was intercepted.*
>
> *She let loose (with) a scream.*

'She let loose with a scream' is the intransitive example. M-W does not add a caveat.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let_loose) is clearer:

> *let loose* (1) (transitive, idiomatic) To free; to release from
>   restraint.

(this is the usual sense)

> *... the unholy ambitions which let loose this horror ...*

........

> (2) (intransitive, idiomatic, sometimes followed by with or on) To
>   shout, make a loud sound, or perform a sudden, vehement action; to
>   behave in a raucous, frenzied manner.
>
> *He set his teeth, and let loose with a fury before which nothing could stand; and Maurice was forced back step by step until he was
>   almost up with the wall.*

...................

'Dogs are let loose' is just the passive transformation of 'They let the dogs loose', Wiktionary sense (1)

...................

'Ellen was laughing like a child let loose in a sweet shop' uses a reduced relative clause (from 'Ellen was laughing like a child that had been let loose in a sweet shop').